# Testing if Discord invite link is invalid?

Tags: c#, discord

I am trying to make an application that tests Discord invite links and checks if they are invalid or valid. However, I do not know how to do this.

Answer (score 5):

Use a GET request to the [invite endpoint](https://discordapp.com/developers/docs/resources/invite#get-invite).

---

Request:

```
GET: https://discordapp.com/api/invite/obviously-invalid-invite-code
```

Response (HTTP status 404):

```
{
    "code": 10006,
    "message": "Unknown Invite"
}
```

---

You can do this by using a `WebRequest` call to the endpoint, and catching a `WebException` that gets thrown when the API returns 404.

```
try
{
    WebRequest request = WebRequest.Create("https://discordapp.com/api/invites/obviously-invalid-invite-code");
    request.Method = "GET";

    HttpWebResponse response = (HttpWebResponse)request.GetResponse();

    if (response.StatusCode == HttpStatusCode.OK) // and possibly other checks in the response contents
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Invite link is valid");
    }
} 
catch (WebException wex)
{
    if (((HttpWebResponse)wex.Response).StatusCode == HttpStatusCode.NotFound)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Invite link is invalid");
    }
    // You may need to account for other 400/500 statuses
    else throw wex;
}
```

Comment: How would I print out the response that the GET returns?

Comment: @RedstoneUmbreon I've added a brief example.

Comment: I was trying to use a web request but wasn't sure how to do so. Thanks man. :) 

Comment: I just tested the code, it works but, it returns valid to links that are invalid. It only returns invalid to links that are longer than 7 characters.

Comment: Invites that are expired, revoked or never existed still return 404 Not Found, and should be caught by the exception handling above. If you're still having issues, you should [post a new question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask) referencing this one, with any additional information required to reproduce the issue.