# How do I check if an invite link is valid or not on Discord.js?

Tags: discord, discord.js

How do I make the bot check if the invite link posted on a channel (a lot of channels) is valid or not? I've searched around here, google, github and discord servers but I wasn't able to get an answer.. I'm coding the bot with Discord.js, and any help would be appreciated!

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Testing if discord invite link is invalid?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52657141/testing-if-discord-invite-link-is-invalid)

Answer (score 4):

As suggested in the comments, you should use the [invite endpoint](https://discord.com/developers/docs/resources/invite#get-invite). You can use your preferred method to create a `GET` request, but here's an example with [`node-fetch`](https://npmjs.com/package/node-fetch):

```js
const fetch = require('node-fetch');

const code = 'this-is-invalid';

fetch(`https://discordapp.com/api/invite/${code}`)
 .then((res) => res.json())
 .then((json) => {
  if (json.message === 'Unknown Invite') {
   // the invite is invalid
  } else {
   // the invite is valid
  }
 });
```

---

[Here's what the result object looks like](https://discordapp.com/api/invite/this-is-invalid)